# Create comma separate list for JavaScript from my Query

Tags: php, javascript

Is there a quick easy way to write the results from the query below to just a comma separate list so between the open/close **javascript** tags that will appear:

72,Client contact name, 2860 eof
72,Contact Phone, 2888 eol
72,Email address, 2865 eol and so on?

```
<?php
    $data = array();
    $results = mysql_query('select account_id, display_name, id from field');
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $data[] = $result;
    }
?>
<script language="javascript">
    ???????
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That string is not valid Javascript code. Did you mean the following?

```
var myData = "72,Client contact name, 2860 eof 72,Contact Phone, 2888 eol 72,Email address, 2865 eol";
```

To do that, you can chose to do it in Javascript or PHP. To do it in PHP, use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
<script language="javascript">
    var someData = <?php echo implode(",", $data); ?>;
</script>
```

To do it in Javscript, first pass it over using [json_encode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) then [join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) in Javascript.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var someData = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>.join(",");
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need it as a JavaScript object? Just use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
<?php
    $data = array();
    $results = mysql_query('select account_id, display_name, id from field');
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $data[] = $result;
    }
?>
<script language="javascript">
    var someData = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Not Jason, please.  I don't know what the deal is with Json and the folks around here, I just want to spit out a list and let them run with that.

Comment: it's because JSON is the right way to do it.  A comma separated list isn't valid JavaScript anyway.  Also, please accept my answer for the other question if you're going to use my code to ask a question.